# Form Field Outlining

Tags: css, firefox, macos, forms

I'm trying to remove the blue "halo" outline that form elements have in Firefox on OS X.  Using CSS, I can remove the halo in Safari on OS X, via:

```
input {
  outline: none;
}
```

But this seems to have no effect in Firefox, nor does the -moz-outline property.

Comment: If your using bootstrap, add box-shadow:none;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the various suggestions made here, but none seemed to be able to fully address the problem.  By defining a custom border style, i.e.

```
border: 1px solid #000;
```

I'm able to get rid of the focus halo, but this obviously alters the look of the input element.  `border-style: inset;` seems to most closely resemble the "native" look, but it's still not quite right, so as far as I can tell right now, you can either suppress the halo, or have a natural looking input.

Answer (score 2):

Another option, that takes care of all of the 'halo' is this:

```
*:focus {outline: none;}
```

I guess you could add an `!important` if you wished, but I haven't run into the need yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
:focus {outline:none;}
::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb since I don't have OSX to test it... but does removing the border work?

```
input {
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Nope, this was the first thing I tried.  It'll remove the border, but not the :focus highlighting, which I believe is more related to the outline property.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an active user style sheet in your machine creating this behaviour. Some add-ons do this (to make the focus more obvious).
Look into the firefox's chome forder (in your user files)
Alternatively try with

```
input {outline: none!important;}
```

Also

- The Stylish plugin has a style for this, maybe you have it installed?
- There are greasemonkey script that do this. If you have it installed, disable it

They both take precedence over the !important attribute.

So: you have several places to look into
* User stylesheets
* Stylysh
* greasemonkey
* anothes add-on

One of those must be forcing the outline

Comment: adding !important didn't seem to have any effect.  As far as user style sheet, I've set nothing myself, and if the fix relies on a user altering their local configuration, it won't work.

Comment: Added some clarification, you misunderstood my reply

Answer (score 0):

I believe the style of all the form elements are stored in the `forms.css` file. In OS X, I think it is located here:

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/res/forms.css
```

You may want to browse through that file and see if there is any obvious CSS that is affecting the appearance you are seeing. For example, on Windows the `input` element has `-moz-appearance: textfield;`, which I couldn't find any documentation on, so perhaps there is some "native" `-moz-*` style on those fields that is controlling the glow, something you could possibly override.

The other thing to try might be to override everything in that file by changing the `input` definitions to `input2` or something (after making a copy of course). Then you can see if you can get the glow to stop at all by manipulating the default CSS.

Once you've determined you can make it stop (if you can), you can add styles back in a bit at a time until you find the one that causes the effect you don't want. You can probably speed up that process by eliminating styles from your testing that obviously aren't related (e.g. - `line-height: normal !important;` is almost certainly not responsible for a blue glow around the fields).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
input:focus { outline: none; }
```